# I'm trying to build the apk using the Ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using this command:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias hungrill -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000`

It asked to enter the password, but I forgot the password.

Comment: From Review: Would you please EDIT your post and include a question at the end, telling what exactly do you need? Also, please avoid posting details on comments to your own question. Thanks

Comment: Improved grammar and spelling